# Can that multiple matrix product become the unit-matrix?

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, matrix-equations

From consideration of a wider problem I get the following multiple matrixproduct and intuitively I assume, that matrixproduct cannot become the unit-matrix.

Let the example matrices be the following, but may be this can already be answered in general.
$$  A = \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & -\sqrt{0.5}& \sqrt{0.5}  \\
 -\sqrt{0.5} & 1/2 & 1/2  \\
 \sqrt{0.5}&   1/2 & 1/2       \\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad \text{ Note: } A=A^{-1}=A^t
$$
$$  D = \text{diagonal} \left(\begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & ß^{-1} & ß  \end{bmatrix} \right) 
\qquad \qquad \text{ where } ß = 3 + 2 \sqrt 2
$$

> Q: I have now the fourfold parametrizable matrixproduct, and ask, whether -for any combinations of $\; k_j \in \mathbb Z \backslash 0 \;$ - I can get equality:
> $$ [x,y,z] \cdot A \cdot D^{k_1} \cdot A \cdot D^{k_3}  \overset?= [x,y,z] \cdot D^{k_0} \cdot A \cdot D^{k_2} \cdot A \tag 1
> $$

I think it is also equivalent to the question involving the matrices alone (*without* the leading row-dotmultiplication by vector $[x,y,z]$ ):

> Q: can occur equality in the equation
> $$  A \cdot D^{k_1} \cdot A \cdot D^{k_3} \cdot A \cdot D^{-k_2} \cdot A \cdot D^{-k_0}  \overset?=  I  \tag 2
> $$

This latter form might have a general, elementary answer, but I'm unsure of that, and also, whether the removal of the row-dotproduct doesn't change the characteristic of possible equality in(1).

---

***update:*** I see, that $B_k = A \cdot D^k \cdot A $ is symmetric. Then from (1) I take
$$  B_{k_1} \cdot D^{k_3}  \overset?= D^{k_0} \cdot B_{k_2} \tag 3
$$
On the lhs I've the columnscaling and on the rhs I've a rowscaling, so even more I think there should no (nontrivial:$k_j \ne 0$) solution. Is this observation sufficient?

---

*(Impossibility of a solution for (1) seems to allow a sought disproof in my wider problem)*

Comment: One can always find some $k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3\ne0$ and some row vector $(x,y,z)$ such that $(1)$ holds. In fact, for any two integers $m$ and $n$, $K=AD^mAD^n-D^nAD^mA$ is a skew-symmetric matrix of odd dimensions. Therefore it is singular and $(x,y,z)K=0$ has a non-trivial solution.

Comment: @user1551 -ah, thanks for your answer; just created an example solution. So I'm taking this to find out, whether the selection of 2 parameters $(n,m)$ only is perhaps a violation of nontriviality in my problem... I'll see...